# Merge two seperate phpunit code coverage reports to form a single report

Tags: php, phpunit, code-coverage

I have two separate sets of tests, unit tests and integration tests. Both of which can generate code coverage reports in the variety of usual outputs, php, html, xml, text, clover, crap4j. It's the usual choices from https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-code-coverage.

However I need to get a single code coverage report. Is there an existing solution to do this? If not my current thought process is that I need to generate two separate php coverage reports then create a new report from those by parsing and merging the arrays.

Answer (score 1):

I found a repo which solves this issue https://github.com/Nimut/phpunit-merger